# Using yq version 4 to modify a .yaml to add & and * characters not in quotes

Tags: yq

Ive got a requirement to update the bitbucket pipelines yaml file by adding a task definition to the pipelines.branches.develop set of steps (adding it to be the first step, while keeping any existing steps) and if the develop branch pipeline doesn't exist, create it with the specified task definition as a step.

yq command im using the add to the develop pipeline is below:

```
yq '.pipelines.branches.develop = [{"step":"*My-Step"}] + .pipelines.branches.develop' bitbucket-pipelines.yml
```

This works but its enclosing the '*My-Step' in quotes and I cant work out how to remove them without causing the command to fail.

I have the same problem with the '&' character for my addition to the definition steps.

Could someone provide some guidance, or documentation.

Comment: Did you just search for it? See https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/

Comment: @Inian yes, i tried following the instructions on this page but they didnt appear to have examples I needed, I have managed to get something working the way Id like but just have a minor issue now with the characters & and * in the step definition and the pipelines call to the step, ive updated my original question with these snippets

Comment: Post a sample input YAML and show an _exact_ expected output for the same. Only then we could try and attempt a possible solution with `yq`

Answer (score 1):

The `*` and `&` characters aren't actually part of the field name - they are special characters in yaml used as aliases and anchors (basically for reusing blocks of content in the file.

You will need to use special expressions to update them separately from the string value: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/anchor-and-alias-operators.

Here is what you probably need:

```bash
yq '.pipelines.branches.develop = [( {"step":null} | .step alias="My-Step")] + .pipelines.branches.develop '
```

The important bit is the awkward looking expression here:

`( {"step":null} | .step alias="My-Step")`

Which is creating a new map with a `step` key and then separately setting the alias to 'My-Step'.

Disclaimer: I wrote yq